# How to fetch certain values from a table based on several condition in SQL

Tags: sql

[image: EXCEL SHEET DATA]

Sample records I have shown in Excel. I am looking for a SQL query for the following conditions:

1. On 31-01-2023 emp mode is BUS
2. If emp mode is bus on 31-01-2023 then  for 28-02-2023 it should be only CAR
3. On 28-02-2023 emp mode should only be CAR
4. looking only for 31-01-2023 and 28-02-2023

Is it possible to write a SQL for this?

[image]

query to satisfy all these conditions

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS: if you're looking for mentioned dates and modes.

```
Select * from 'table_name' where (date='31-01-2023' OR date ='28-02-2023') AND (mode ='BUS' OR Mode='CAR');
```

Comment: if any problem occurs , then  do let me know.

Comment: please see my comments below for the below query

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
Select * from 'table_name' where (date='31-01-2023' OR date ='28-02-2023') AND (mode ='BUS' OR Mode='CAR');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.EMPNO
    FROM table a JOIN table b USING EMPNO
    WHERE a.DATE = '31-01-2023' and a.MODE = 'BUS'
    AND b.DATE = '28-02-2023' and  b.MODE = 'CAR';
```

This opens the table once as `a` and then again as `b` and then looks for records with the same `EMPNO` that meet the specified condition.

Comment: THERE ARE SOME DATA WHICH HAVE RECORD FOR ONLY 28-02-2023 , THOSE RECORDS ARE NOT FETCHED IN MY SAMPLE. it fetchesempno which have records for both  28-02-2023, and 31-01-2023 , Some records which have only 28-02-2023 and some have records only until 31-01-2023 , these conditions are not matched , these rows are not fetched.any suggestion to fetch those records also

Comment: Can you please provide suggestion for the above ask as well

Comment: since we are making join on empnumbers

Comment: If you want to fetch null values for the missing half when you only match one of the conditions, then you could change `JOIN` to `FULL OUTER JOIN` in the query above.

Comment: still after using full outer join the results are same @Matthias Fripp 
Any other suggestions would really help, thanks in advance